# dask pivot_table seems very slow

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm collating a simple pivot table on which position was owned by which fund on which date. It reads a fairly large parquet file per day, extracting just 3 columns. Resultant for 1 year is ~100K rows, 365 columns, each element containing Nan or a single short string (for "fund").

This takes 46 seconds for one year of data, if I fall back to pandas before creating the pivot table.

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet("s3://.../2021*.parquet", columns=["as_of_date", "position_id", "fund"]).categorize(columns=['as_of_date'])
ddf.compute().pivot_table(index='position_id', columns='as_of_date', values='fund', aggfunc='first')
```

However, that seems like I'm pushing a lot of data around, I would think it'd be more efficient, or at least  as efficient to have dask do the pivot table:

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet("s3://.../2021*.parquet", columns=["as_of_date", "position_id", "fund"]).categorize(columns=['as_of_date'])
ddf.pivot_table(index='position_id', columns='as_of_date', values='fund', aggfunc='first').compute()
```

But that takes 12 minutes, and if I give it more than 1 year of data, dies a with KilledWorker exception.

Any guidance as to how to diagnose what's going on here? I'm not clear why it struggles so much to do the pivot_table. FWIW, there are no duplicates, but pivot() doesn't exist in dask, so aggfunc='first' is the simplest placeholder I can think of to make it work

Comment: see the [dask best practices guide](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/best-practices.html). generally, if you can do it in pandas, it's going to be faster in pandas. dask is great for large, compute-constrained operations and memory-constrained embarrassingly parallel workflows. pivoting an in-memory dataframe is very memory intensive and requires reshuffling and resizing all data, so this is kryptonite for dask.

Answer (score 0):

Performing some operations on dask dataframes currently can lead to bottlenecks in processing. These bottlenecks can cause memory problems or leading to a inefficient data shuffling. Pivoting is one such operation. This can be seen on the DAG for a sample pivot:

```py
from dask.datasets import timeseries

df = timeseries(end="2000-01-05").categorize(columns=["name"])

pivot = df.pivot_table(index="id", columns="name", values="x")

pivot.visualize()
```

As the number of partitions increases, the DAG will get more involved. To see that try increasing the kwarg `end="2000-01-05"` to a later date.

Comment: The ironic thing is there's one file per date, so each column is completely independent of the others. Maybe pivot is just the wrong way to go about this, though it works fine in pandas.

Comment: Well, for cases like these there is always `delayed` API...